# How to make a program in a pipe not to be executed until the first data arrive without tempfile?

Tags: bash, curl, pipe

Specific case:

```
generate_data | curl -T - http://someserver/path
```

That means, I have a program that generate an output in the stdout, and I put that on a remote server with curl.

The problem is that if `generate_data` takes too much time, the server is going to return 408.

I know that pipes execute all the commands without waiting for data to be ready, so my next iteration was:

```
generate_data | ( sleep 20 ; curl -T - http://someserver/path )
```

The time was twice the max time needed to run generate_data, so all the things are ok. But... it is not a optimal solution.

I know I can create something more complex with read, and a proper shell script, but have the feeling that I an missing something obvious.

So... What can i use instead of the `sleep 20;` without creating a temp file?

Comment: how much data is there going to be? how about writing out a temp file, e.g. `generate_data > tempfile ; curl -T tempfile ...`

Comment: Be grateful that the `sleep` works! ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

```
generate_data > /tmp/generated_data; cat /tmp/generated_data | curl -T - http://someserver/path
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that on the questions, that I don't want to use a tempfile. Using a tempfile, the proper solution, including a clean up, will be something like.

``generate_data > /tmp/asdf && curl -T /tmp/asdf http://server/path ; ( [ -f /tmp/asdf && rm /tmp/asdf )``

Comment: Do you want curl to start sending as soon as the first data is generated or do you want it to wait until data has finished being generated? In other words, is the problem that you're taking too long to generate data or that there is some process that happens before any output begins?